# Android testing: verify onClickListener using private anonymous class

Tags: java, android, mockito, robolectric

I am using Robolectric and Mockito and want to verify that async task is started or not.
Here is my code:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    alert.setTitle(R.string.warning_text);
    alert.setMessage(message);
    alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, yesListener);
    alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, noListener);
    alert.show();

private DialogInterface.OnClickListener yesListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
        startAsyncTask();
    }
};
```

Here is my test case

```
AlertDialog warningDialog = ShadowAlertDialog.getLatestAlertDialog();
Assert.assertTrue(warningDialog.isShowing());
warningDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick();
verify(mySpy).startAsyncTask();
```

The test fails at verify and getting "Wanted but not invoked" error. However onClick method does fire.

But when defining the listener in line like below, it works

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
alert.setTitle(R.string.warning_text);
alert.setMessage(message);
alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i){
        startAsyncTask();
    }
});

alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i){
        dialogInterface.dismiss();
    }
});
alert.show();
```

Can any one tell what is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1):

> Can any one tell what is the difference between the two?

Not sure if this is the problem, but in the first declaration you have `yesListener` and `noListener`:

```
alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, yesListener);
alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, noListener);
```

while the click listener is named `driverOkClickListener`, which appears to be unused:

```
private DialogInterface.OnClickListener driverOkClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
        startAsyncTask();
    }
};
```

Parhaps you wanted `driverOkClickListener` instead of `yesListener`?

Comment: yeah, driverOkClickListener should be the yesListener. It is the typo mistake while asking question

Answer (score 1):

**Found the solution!**

In your Robolectric tests you need to call the following method after `performClick` or `callOnClick`.

Example:

```
alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick()
ShadowLooper.runUiThreadTasks()
```

After this the contents of the `onClickListener` on Positive and Negative buttons are executed.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example you don't `set` the listener to your dialog:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    alert.setTitle(R.string.warning_text);
    alert.setMessage(message);
    alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, driverOkClickListener);
    alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, driverOkClickListener);
    alert.show();

...

private DialogInterface.OnClickListener driverOkClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
            startAsyncTask();
        } else {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    }
};
```